# Finding maximum amount of approximately same number c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, bitmap

I am getting a list of RGB colors from a bitmap image. Now i want to separate the **maximum** '*approximate*' same numbers.

i.e

245, 230,230 **and** 235, 230, 230   should be considered as the same (maximum difference is 5).

I am succeeded in extracting the same numbers and obviously also knew how to find the find the max in a number but can't figure out how to tell the algorithm to consider the difference of 10-30 as the same number.

Here is my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
   {
      if (y < bmp.Height && y > 0)
      {
         c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
         if (db.Contains(c.R.ToString() + " " + c.G.ToString() + " " + c.B.ToString()) == false)
         {
            if (i == 0)
            {                   
               db.Add(c.R.ToString() + " " + c.G.ToString() + " " + c.B.ToString());
            }
         }
         else
            i++;
      }
   }
}

foreach (string dbs in db)
   richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + dbs+Environment.NewLine;

//same amount of numbers not written above are:
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + i.ToString()+ Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Why do you convert it to string? If you didn't convert it to string, you could compare its RGB values.

Comment: Can you give more examples of numbers which can be considered the same or different?

Comment: Its not only about RGB or string or whatever... It is simply that how to consider the approximate values as a single value!

Comment: 245, 230,230 and 235, 230, 230, difference is 10 right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes its 10.. and it can vary from 0 to 30.

Comment: This can lead to a big issue. For example (245, 230, 230) is equaled with (215, 230, 230), and (215, 230, 230) is also equaled with (185, 230, 230), but (245, 230, 230) is not equaled (185, 230, 230). How can you resolve this logic issue?

Comment: Take one RGB that is maximum times in a bitmap and compare that RGB value to others

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For each pixel in the image, count how many pixels are "close" (or "approximately the same") to its RGB color value. Then find the pixel(s) with the maximum count of "close" pixels.

Complexity O(n^2) where n is the total number of pixels in the image (n=w*h)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need some formula like this pseudocode:

```
bSameColors(pixel a, pixel b, uint threshold) = 
  (Max(Abs(a.R - b.R), Max(Abs(a.G - b.G), Abs(a.B - b.B))) < threshold)
```

But if you want to make some color clustering, consider comparison with mean color value of cluster

Answer (score 1):

The distance between to things can be calculated in many ways:

The **euclid distance** `sqrt( (r1-r2)^2 + (g1-g2)^2 +(b1-b2)^2 )`  would be the way to describe closeness (^ == pow ). The difference being less than 10, would be a sphere of radius 10, which would enclose the second point.

The **manhatten distance** would be `abs(r1-r2) + abs(b1-b2) + abs(g1-g2)`.  This would be driving round manhatten, and a grid system, saying no more than 10 blocks in any direction.

If just **individual components** matter, then they are the same if: `abs(r1-r2) < 10 AND abs(g1-g2) < 10 AND abs(b1-b2) < 10`

For colours, **similar colours** are better defined in alternative colour space (e.g. [wikipedia lab colour space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space))

These are tuned to the **human eyes**, and close values for these spaces will compute to similar LAB/XYZ values. For RGB, some "similar" values look radically different.